# value of loop variable is null after SSH connection

Tags: linux, bash

I am trying to write a script that will do ssh and run a few commands on the remote host with help of loop. One of the problems I've run into is that, when I run the for loop, it outputs is null.

```
migration_array=($1)
Environment=$2

case "$Environment" in

       "Feature")
                echo "Running test on Feature"
                ssh -tt jenkins@10.0.10.100 -p 1234 <<EOF
                for i in ${migration_array[@]}; do
                   echo "file: $i"
                done
                exit
EOF
       ;;

        *)
            echo "unknown environment!"
        ;;

esac
```

**Output**

```
Last login: Thu Feb 13 15:52:43 2020 from 10.0.10.88

jenkins@feature:~$ 
>                    do
>                    echo "file: "
>                 done
file: 
jenkins@ffeature:~$                 exit
logout
Connection to 10.0.10.100 closed.
```

Comment: Sorry I have no idea what you are saying. Your words seem to be jumbled. Please proof-read and edit your question.

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor I have edit the question.

Answer (score 0):

I got it working by adding the slash to loop variable,

```
echo "file: \$i"
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not null, it is an empty string (not the same thing).

The problem you are having is the variable is being expanded early by the here doc (`<<`). You need it to be expanded latter, by the `ssh`. Therefore escape the `$` so that it is passed to `ssh`, by putting a `\` in front of it.